# Access form_for params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Ive been trying this for two days. How can I access form params in controller? I am using rails 4 form_for.

Below is my code. Ive tried all the commented ways but not fruitfull. Am calling def patient_params with .ajax to get the required data. Help

## controller

```
    def new
     @patient = Patient.new
     @regions = Luregion.all
     @districts = Ludistrict.all
   end

  def update_dis
   #@dis = Ludistrict.where("luregion_id =?", params[:luregion_id])
   #@dis = Ludistrict.where("luregion_id =?", params[:patient][:luregion_id])
   #@dis = Ludistrict.where("luregion_id =?", params[:patient[:luregion_id]])
   @dis = Ludistrict.where("luregion_id =?", '#{qaz}')
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json {render json: @dis}
    end
  end

    def patient_params
     params.require(:patient).permit(:fname, :lname, :sex, :dob, :startdate,
                                  :phone, :guardian, :address, :ludistricts_id,
                                  :luta_id, :luvillages_id, :luregion_id)
end
```

## html view source

```
<select id="patient_luregion_id" name="patient[luregion_id]"><option value=""></option>
<input id="patient_luvillages_id" name="patient[luvillages_id]" type="text" /></p>
```

Comment: `params[:patient][:luregion_id]` or `patient_params[:luregion_id]` should work. Try to see the params you receive in server log.

Comment: Your question answer is in your console log, just check it. or you can see all the parameters in `params`. you can see it by `render json: params` in json format